# How to import JSON values inside MySQL (10.2.36-MariaDB) table?

Tags: json, mariadb

I have the following JSON file :

```
{
  "ID": 5464015,
  "CUSTOMER_ID": 1088020,
  "CUSOTMER_NAME": "My customer 1"
}
{
  "ID": 5220812,
  "CUSTOMER_ID": 523323,
  "CUSOTMER_NAME": "My customer 2"
}
{
  "ID": 5205039,
  "CUSTOMER_ID": 1934806,
  "CUSOTMER_NAME": "My customer 3"
}
```

From a shell script, I would like to import these values into a MariaDB table (MariaDB Server version : 10.2.36-MariaDB) with the related columns already created :

- ID
- CUSTOMER_ID
- CUSTOMER_NAME

But for CUSTOMER_NAME, I don't want to import double quotes at the beginning and at the end of the value.
Is there a simple way to do it?

Or if not possible, If I have a txt or csv file like this :

```
5464015,1088020,"My customer 1"
5220812,523323,"My customer 2"
5205039,1934806,"My customer 3"
```

How to import it?

Many thanks

Comment: @Akina : ok, do you have an example inside a script? just to understand correctly ;-)

Comment: The solution for MariaDB added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution which must work on 10.2.36-MariaDB (all used constructions are legal for this version):

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (ID INT, CUSTOMER_ID INT, CUSTOMER_NAME VARCHAR(255))
WITH RECURSIVE
cte1 AS ( SELECT LOAD_FILE('C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/json.txt') jsondata ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT 1 level, CAST(jsondata AS CHAR) oneobject, jsondata 
          FROM cte1
          UNION ALL
          SELECT level + 1,
                 TRIM(SUBSTRING(jsondata FROM 1 FOR 2 + LOCATE('}', jsondata))),
                 TRIM(SUBSTRING(jsondata FROM 1 + LOCATE('}', jsondata) FOR LENGTH(jsondata)))
          FROM cte2
          WHERE jsondata != '' )
SELECT oneobject->>"$.ID" ID,
       oneobject->>"$.CUSTOMER_ID" CUSTOMER_ID,
       oneobject->>"$.CUSTOMER_NAME" CUSTOMER_NAME
FROM cte2 WHERE level > 1;
```

Tested on MySQL 8.0.16 (I have no available MariaDB now):

[image]

The content of `json.txt` file matches shown in the question (misprint in attribute name edited).

[image]

PS. Of course the SELECT itself may be used for to insert the data into existing table.

Comment: ok thanks I will have a look on this. but could be much more easier to use a file like this :  5464015,1088020,"My customer 1" instead of a JSON file ?

Comment: @TooNetCreation *but could be much more easier to use a file like this* Maybe. Use the format that is more convenient for you.

Comment: This solution does **not work** on any **MariaDB** version. The `->>` operator is not part of the MariaDB syntax. 

For MariaDB > 10.5 see @Akina's other solution. I have sketched a solution from 10.2.2 to 10.5 here: [db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=8f9d502ee65b4dcdba5a64c174d86e42)

Comment: @MikeF. Nothing prevents JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT()) usage in MariaDB.

Comment: @Akina What do you mean by that? Does this relate to my comment about the `->>` operator or the sketched solution?

Comment: @MikeF. I mean that `column->>'path'` and `JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(column, 'path'))` is absolutely the same.

Comment: @Akina If so, please edit the answer accordingly. However, it still doesn't seem to work [db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=e19d20c738071119ec0b9948817a4c1c)

Comment: @MikeF. You set incorrect data into `@data` variable - the commas are lost. And server explicitly tells that the value is not valid JSON.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246095/discussion-between-mike-f-and-akina).

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test (ID INT, CUSTOMER_ID INT, CUSTOMER_NAME VARCHAR(255));
> ```

> ```
> SET @data := '
> [  { "ID": 5464015,
>      "CUSTOMER_ID": 1088020,
>      "CUSTOMER_NAME": "My customer 1"
>    },
>    { "ID": 5220812,
>      "CUSTOMER_ID": 523323,
>      "CUSTOMER_NAME": "My customer 2"
>    },
>    { "ID": 5205039,
>      "CUSTOMER_ID": 1934806,
>      "CUSTOMER_NAME": "My customer 3"
>    }
> ]
> ';
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO test
> SELECT *
> FROM JSON_TABLE(@data,
>                 "$[*]" COLUMNS( ID INT PATH "$.ID",
>                                 CUSTOMER_ID INT PATH "$.CUSTOMER_ID",
>                                 CUSTOMER_NAME VARCHAR(255) PATH "$.CUSTOMER_NAME")
>                ) AS jsontable;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM test;
> ```

| ID | CUSTOMER_ID | CUSTOMER_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5464015 | 1088020 | My customer 1 |
| 5220812 | 523323 | My customer 2 |
| 5205039 | 1934806 | My customer 3 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6608f89efe34103fa1e4cd181e619aa8)*

Comment: As I'm using MariaDB I get this error on INSERT TO instruction : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(@data,
                "$[*]" COLUMNS( ID INT PATH "$.ID",
                 ...' at line 3

Comment: @TooNetCreation :facepalm: Why you have written "inside **MySQL** table" in the subject??? Who have tagged the question as MySQL-related??? Edit, re-tag... and specify PRECISE server version.

Comment: my apologies you're right...bad habit. post #1 has been updated. server version : 10.2.36-MariaDB

Comment: MariaDB have no JSON_TABLE() function or something similar - this answer is not applicable to it.

Comment: OK. I have edited post 1 with new infos. If I can format this file to be a simple txt ou csv file, is it possible to import values inside maria db database/table ?

Comment: @TooNetCreation If you will format your file to a form "one object in one row" then the task will be easy enough in MariaDB (but nevertheless it needs to use stored procedure and temporary table).

Comment: ok I see. do you have an idea about this script or stored procedure to do it?

Comment: **MariaDB 10.6** now do have the `JSON_TABLE()` statement, so this solution now works also for MariaDB DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to php a simple script is a good method, as it can turn json into an array (and automatically remove said quotes around text) and then you can decide what columns in the json equate to what mysql columns.

Depending on your mysql version you may have access to this utility to inport json from command line
https://mysqlserverteam.com/import-json-to-mysql-made-easy-with-the-mysql-shell/
But it may not work if your columns don't match perfectly with the MySQL columns ( I belieivd it is not case sensitive however )

Comment: thanks, I will ask my hosting provider ;-)